# Testing Jersey Resource and UriInfo not set

Tags: java, jersey, mockito

I am trying to test a resource created in Jersey using Mockito, but I seem to have hit a wall. Part of my resource involves returning a location header - which in turn is made up of the UriInfo injected at runtime. However when doing simple unit tests using JUnit4, the uriInfo is not being set - is there any way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using Jersey's provided test harness / framework or hand rolling it all in Mockito yourself? IME the former works, the latter never does.

Answer (score 0):

there is no `@Context` auto injection without jersey runtime env.
Otherwise, you could use `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` to inject the mocked objects.